# Fast Protocol for adding elements to Kafka with minimal latency?

Tags: apache-kafka

What would be the protocol for a client to add elements to Kafka in a very fast manner with minimal latency for the client? Should I be using something like RPC/raw tcp instead of http ? I want to add these in a fire and forget manner , is there a udp option to add such items as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to directly interact with a Kafka cluster is via the Kafka protocol. It's a binary protocol over TCP, for the full details, see: https://kafka.apache.org/protocol. This is what Kafka clients implement.

There are a few proxies/bridges that allow to interact via HTTP, AMQP and a few other protocols but these end up using the Kafka protocol to connect to the cluster so not only they have worse performance but they often offer less features than the Kafka protocol.

Kafka is designed with speed in mind so the protocol is very efficient. It also supports requests batching so you can find the sweet "latency vs throughput" spot for your use case.

Regarding "fire and forget", you can specify the required acknowledgement when producing data to Kafka using the `acks` setting. When set to 0, the Producer will not wait for any feedback from the cluster, see: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs